# Configure Linux I2C Speed

Tags: performance, linux-kernel, i2c

I am using I2C on the Snowball board, running at 400KHz by default.

I use the api defined in `<linux/i2c.h>` and configure as follows

```
m_fd = open(m_filename.c_str(), O_RDWR);

if (ioctl(m_fd, I2C_SLAVE_FORCE, m_addr) < 0) 
{
    throw I2cError(DeviceConfigFail);
}
```

How can I change the speed to standard mode (reduce clock rate to 100KHz)?

Comment: I don't believe you can do this from user mode.  The issue is that all peripherals on the `i2c` bus use the same clock.  You can find your machine file (or device tables) and change the clock there.  Here is the `i2c` user docs https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the I2C SCL frequency in your driver's 'struct i2c_gpio_platform_data'.

```
    static struct i2c_gpio_platform_data xyz_i2c_gpio_data = {
    .sda_pin = GPIO_XYZ_SDA,
    .scl_pin = GPIO_XYZ_SCL,
    .udelay = 5, //@udelay: signal toggle delay. SCL frequency is (500 / udelay) kHz
    ....
};
```

Changing 'udelay' changes your 'xyz' i2c device's clock frequency.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `I2C Frequency` in driver source file of the corresponding peripheral (ie: `Slave device` to which you are communicating through I2C. Example: `EEPROM`/`Camera` etc.)

You may find some macro defined in that driver source code... like:

```
#define EEPROM_I2C_FREQ 400000 //400KHz
```

Change it to:

```
#define EEPROM_I2C_FREQ 100000 //100KHz
```

Only for that corresponding driver, I2C frequency/speed will be changed.

Comment: Where do I find this driver source file?

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r It depends on your driver. In linux drivers will be in /drivers/YourDriver folder. Eg: EEPROM driver in /drivers/EEPROM folder!